# Visual Studio C++ warning for no default constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, default-constructor

Is there a warning in Visual Studio I can turn on for C++ to tell me when a class doesn't have a default constructor? The only ones I can find are [C4623](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dk81ahy.aspx), [C4510](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf74y2b.aspx) and [C2512](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zkz8dx6.aspx) but they're for specific problems with the default constructor.

I'm currently using VS2013.

Update: I'm not saying there's anything wrong with not having a default constructor, I'm asking if there's an optional warning for it.

Comment: What is the problem with no default constructor?

Comment: It is perfectly normal and expected for a class not to have a user-defined default constructor. If a warning were issued for this, you'd drown in them - I suspect there are hundreds of such classes in the C++ standard library alone.

Comment: You can just like `STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof( T{} ) > 0 )`. It focuses on ability to default construct, not that there is a user defined default constructor.

Comment: Since you're using VS2013, you can use `static_assert` directly with Alf comment

Comment: technically there always is a default constructor, it can be either user defined or compiler-created

Comment: @Swift: No; the compiler will not create a default constructor if there is *any* user-defined constructor. That is to say, defining `Foo::Foo(int)` stops the compiler from creating `Foo::Foo()`.